# Marginal Likelihood in PYMC

Tags: model-selection, python, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I am using the PYMC toolbox in python in order to carry out a model selection problem using MCMC. What I would like to have for each model is the marginal log-likelihood (i.e. model evidence).

The question:
After I've run my sampler on the model, like

```
mc = MCMC(myModel)
```

does the following command return the marginal log-likelihood?

```
myModel.logp
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: So, it is clear now that the answer to the above is a definite no: lop does not return the marginal log-likelihood. However, I am skeptical as to whether it does really return the log-posterior for the current sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this returns the log-posterior for the current values of the model parameters.  You need to integrate this value over all model parameters to calculate the evidence.  Here is [a start on a way](http://healthyalgorithms.com/2009/08/25/mcmc-in-python-pymc-for-bayesian-model-selection/), and [here is a possibly missing) blog on a different way](http://stronginference.com/weblog/2010/12/16/estimating-bayes-factors-using-pymc.html).

Comment: The first link seems to describe the harmonic mean estimator, which has poor convergence, see https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The negative answer above is already useful. Though I cannot imagine what a "log-posterior for the current values" means. I know that this is also mentioned in the documentation. I am experienced in Bayesian statistics but have never used MCMC, I try to use variational methods instead when possible.

Comment: So the myModel.logp function returns an approximation to the true log(p(theta|data)) for the last sample theta saved in myModel?

Comment: that is my understanding

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abraham. In danger of breaking etiquette and asking a separate question: how can I calculate the average over all samples and not just the last sample? (I will edit my question above accordingly later.)

Comment: I suggest that you make a new question for this, and include whatever you have tried so far.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask